# jQuery set cookie for first visit

Tags: jquery, cookies

I got a script like that (I use [jQuery cookie js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to set cookies) to display layer on first visit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var visited = $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });

        if (visited == null) {
            $('.newsletter_layer').show();
            $.cookie('visited', 'yes'); 
            alert($.cookie("visited"));         
        }
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunatelly something is not working. I think something is wrong with the if statement. Anyone have idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you are creating the cookie, it will never be null. You need to change your logic to first check if the cookie exists. If not, show the `.newsletter_layer` element, then set the cookie value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // check cookie
        var visited = $.cookie("visited")

        if (visited == null) {
            $('.newsletter_layer').show();
            alert($.cookie("visited"));         
        }

        // set cookie
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody stumbles across this 6 years into the future like I, I got this to work with modification:

Replace: $.cookie -> Cookies