# Finding current visit timestamp in analytics.js

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, universal-analytics

For ga.js, the current visit time stamp could be obtained from __utma cookie.

94963603.208546995.1382512607.1383567288.**1383658500**.9

The part in bold gives us the current session time stamp.

In analytics.js from the cookie,

GA1.2.234136081.1383646137

we have initial visit time stamp. How do we find current visit(session) time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

Analytics.js moved session information to the server level. You no longer have the current session timestamp in the cookie and need to gather it some other way.

Comment: Can you suggest 'some other way'?

Comment: Add your own cookie // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173947/jquery-set-cookie-for-first-visit